# Does minimum variance imply a maximum for ess?

Tags: variance, sample-size, importance-sampling

Does minimum of variance of weights

$$ \text{var}(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i }^n {x_i}^2 - \frac{1}{n^2} \left({\sum_{i }^n {x_i}}\right)^2 $$

imply the maximum of  Kish's approximate formula for computing effective sample size defined as

$$ESS = \frac{\left({\sum_{i }^n {x_i}}\right)^2}{\sum_{i }^n {x_i}^2}$$

At first thought it was trivial and divide and see, but got the following expression

$$ \text{var}(x) = \frac{\left({\sum_{i }^n {x_i}}\right)^2}{n^2} \left( \frac{n}{ESS} - 1 \right) $$

which seems to show it, except the first term on the RHS is not a constant but depends on the values as well.

Comment: it all depends on what you compare: if you have two sets of weights $(x_i)$ and $(y_i)$ how are they produced? The first term in your last formula is not scale invariant, while ESS is.